# How to use the "browser.runtime.sendMessage()" method?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I just started developing my own extension for Firefox and I was wondering if anyone knows how to use the "browser.runtime.sendMessage()" and "browser.runtime.onMessage()".
And yes I have read the official documentation, but it's still not clear to me.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your background/content/popup script add `browser.runtime.sendMessage("your message")` from where ever you want to send a message.

Add the below code to the script from wherever you want to listen to the message.

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage)
function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse){
  console.log(request); //logs "your message"
}
```

Comment: I see, but what if the receiving script is in a new tab that just opened but isn't loaded yet? will it still get the message? how do you make the sender wait for the tab to load?

Comment: you can use 'tabs.tabstatus' to check if the loading is completed and then send the message. more info on tabstatus api here < https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/TabStatus >

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onDOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific as to what is unclear to you.

I would recommend that you find a relatively simple extension that does something you want, and then read the code, modify and play with it to learn about using the extension API.  It is a pretty big, complex API, and I find that reading and playing with working code is the best way to learn about it.

There are some samples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples
just search for `runtime.sendMessage` and see if there is one that interest you.